# Picking an Aluminium temperature buffer size to match any given volume of water

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature

It is common to use a temperature buffer of some kind to dampen down the the response time of a temperature sensor in many applications, like cold storage of vaccine and blood. The size of the buffer (and the time delay it introduces) should be designed to replicate the samples being monitored as closely as possible. Common buffers are water, ethylene glycol, sand, glass beads and Aluminium.

I have been referring to the following document... https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6438558/

I'm interested in using a cylinder of solid Aluminium with a hole drilled though the center for my  for my sensor as a temperature buffer.  Ideally, I would like to represent 10ml, 15ml, 20ml and 30ml of water.

The document I refereed to above gives an equation that can supposedly assist in this process but unfortunately I don't fully understand how it all ties together. I was wondering if somebody could please give me a few pointers or even better, a working example of how I might use that equation to approximate what size of Aluminium could representy 20ml of water.  My understanding of math is not quite up to scratch so please keep it as simple as possible

Perhaps I'm not even on the right track and somebody has a better way of going about solving this problem.

Something I have physically tried was using a ratio of the specific heat and weight for Al. and water but this didn't work out how I thought.  I believe it is more complicated then that due to the difference in surface area but I'm not really sure.

Thanks for taking the time to read my question.

Answer (score 1):

Neglecting the difference in surface area to start with, you could try finding the mass of aluminium that would need the same energy to heat, by 1 degree, as the 10mL of water.

From the specific heat capacity equation $$E=mc\Delta \theta$$

For water

$$E = 10 \times 10^{-6} \times 1000 \times 4200 \times 1$$

(the $10^{-6}$ is to turn mL into cubic meters, and the $1000$ is for the density of water, so everything is in SI units)

For Aluminium $$E = m \times 900 \times 1$$

So the mass of aluminium is $0.0466$ kg.

That has a volume of $1.73 \times 10^{-5}$ cubic meters (using density for aluminium as 2700), or 17.3 cubic centimetres i.e. a cube of side 2.58cm.

The volume required for 20, 30 mL etc...goes up in proportion.  If you want a cylinder shape, probably best with a radius of $r$ and a height of $2r$, then your sensor would be in the middle.

The volume of such a cylinder is

$$V=2\pi r^3$$

and the radii are, for

$10mL$  $1.4cm$

$15mL$  $1.6cm$

$20mL$  $1.76cm$

$30mL$  $2.0cm$

Comment: Thanks John, when I mentioned that I had tried using the using a ratio of the specific heat and weight for Al. and water this is what I meant but I obviously did not explain it very well.  I have a 25mm x 54mm Al. cylinder that I worked out would be equivalent to 15.5ml of water using the same method but the water cooled at a slower rate to the Al. by about 50%.

Comment: @user315511  Maybe the aluminium cylinder was slightly small.  According to the calculation above you'd need (for 15.5mL) r=1.62cm,  i.e diameter and height of 3.24cm instead of 25mm.  Also it could be that the better conduction of the aluminium has an effect

Comment: @user315511 P.S.  The water presumably made a natural seal.  After drilling the hole in the aluminium, did you fill up and seal the hole with something?

Comment: Thanks so much John, You've given me something to thing about. The sensor fitted tightly in the hole I drilled and I used a but of oil for better conduction but I didn't need much

Comment: @user315511  Ok, that's good.  It's hard to model such a thing accurately, with the surface area/conduction etc... changing.  So experiment will probably bring you to the right size of aluminium to use.  Perhaps best to have the size of cylinder so that the sensor is in the middle, if you only have certain sizes of aluminium to choose from you could adapt them by extra lagging...that's all the ideas, all the best...

Comment: Thanks again John, You've help my fundamental understanding of things here and I appreciate it.